# Changing the x-axis for ListLinePlot with more Lists

Tags: list-manipulation, plotting

I'm fighting with a seemingly very simple problem:

I have two lists of data, and want to plot them with `ListLinePlot`. The two lists are only data-points, therefore the following code

```
L1 = {2222, 2500, 5456, 4000, 1000, 6000, 2000, 4000, 2200, 8000, 1800};
L2 = {4500, 6400, 4800, 2600, 2000, 2300, 1800, 2600, 3400, 4500, 2700};
ListLinePlot[{L1, L2}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"phi", "Events"}]
```

produces a plot with x-axis from 1 to 18. However, I want the x-axis (for both lists) being an individual scale.

I know that I can do it like this:

```
L1 = {{10, 2222}, {40, 2500}, {100, 5456}, {120, 4000}, {130, 1000}, {170, 6000}, {172, 2000}, {174, 4000}, {176, 2200}, {177, 8000}, {180, 1800}};
ListLinePlot[{L1}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"phi", "Events"}]
```

But if I want to have the same x-axis for both `L1`, `L2`, I would need to add the axis to both lists. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
L1 = {2222, 2500, 5456, 4000, 1000, 6000, 2000, 4000, 2200, 8000, 1800};
L2 = {4500, 6400, 4800, 2600, 2000, 2300, 1800, 2600, 3400, 4500, 2700};
xr = {10, 40, 100, 120, 130, 170, 172, 174, 176, 177, 180};

ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{xr, L1}], Transpose[{xr, L2}]},
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 AxesLabel -> {"phi", "Events"}]
```

[image]

Comment: faster response and with the plot...+1:)

Answer (score 5):

```
xv = {10, 40, 100, 120, 130, 170, 172, 174, 176, 177, 180};
l1 = {2222, 2500, 5456, 4000, 1000, 6000, 2000, 4000, 2200, 8000, 
   1800};
l2 = {4500, 6400, 4800, 2600, 2000, 2300, 1800, 2600, 3400, 4500, 
   2700};
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xv, #}] & /@ {l1, l2}]
```

Answer (score 5):

[TemporalData](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TemporalData.html) may be quite useful for the purpose:

**Series:**

```
L1 = {2222, 2500, 5456, 4000, 1000, 6000, 2000, 4000, 2200, 8000,  1800};
L2 = {4500, 6400, 4800, 2600, 2000, 2300, 1800, 2600, 3400, 4500,  2700};
```

**Time-stamps:**

```
ts1 = {10, 40, 100, 120, 130, 170, 172, 174, 176, 177, 180};
ts2 = ts1 + 30;
```

**Temporal data  with common time-stamps:**

```
tda = TemporalData[{L1, L2}, {ts1}];
ListLinePlot[tda, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"phi", "Events"}]
```

[image]

**Temporal data with individual time-stamps:**

```
tdb = TemporalData[{L1, L2}, {{ts1}, {ts2}}];
ListLinePlot[tdb, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"phi", "Events"}]
```

[image]